# How to have access to all the table in MySQL data base to my node.js project

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench

I want to have a simple fetch routes in my node.js but my problem is I dont know how to access the other table in mysql

```
router.get('/fetch' , async (req,res)=>{
const allData= await ("The problem is here").findAll({})
res.json(allData)
```

})

I don't know what Model should I put there. I'm using sequelize btw

and here is the list of all my table in mysql [image]

and this is the model available in my node.js
[image]

Comment: I guess, you need to add models for the same for every table in your project. If you are facing any other issue, please mention that clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the response . I see some close solution to my problem which is the sequelize raw queries but I'm just trying to figure it out how to use this. https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/ 
. I'll also try your suggestion and I let you know if that works. Thanks

Comment: @sarvajeetsuman I solved the problem by doing your suggestion thanks. I guess I'll just have to create individual model for all of this mysql table that I imported. because these are all imported from the internet for my lookup data.